How to make mapproxy to use all the zoom levels offered by a tile source?
I can add the following XYZ (orthophoto) layer URL to QGIS: https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/vGBb7WYV10mOJRNM/arcgis/rest/services/2024_Spring_Aerials/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x} and have a tile layer loading tiles down to zoom level 21. Zoom level 21 tiles are higher resolution than zoom level 19 tiles.
I would like to create a WMS using the above URL. To do that, I use mapproxy. Here is my mapproxy.yaml file:
services:
  wms:
    md:
      title: "Lorain County, Ohio WMS"
      abstract: "WMS service for Lorain County, Ohio orthophoto tiles"
    srs: ["EPSG:3857"]
    image_formats: ["image/jpeg"]
  demo:

layers:
  - name: lorain_county_ohio
    title: Lorain County, Ohio Orthophoto Tiles
    sources: [lorain_county_ohio_cache]

caches:
  lorain_county_ohio_cache:
    grids: [global_webmercator]
    sources: [lorain_county_ohio_source]

sources:
  lorain_county_ohio_source:
    type: tile
    url: https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/vGBb7WYV10mOJRNM/arcgis/rest/services/2024_Spring_Aerials/MapServer/tile/%(z)d/%(y)d/%(x)d
    grid: global_webmercator

grids:
  global_webmercator:
    base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR

globals:
  cache:
    base_dir: "./cache_data"
    lock_dir: "./cache_data/locks"

I launch the service via mapproxy-util serve-develop mapproxy.yaml. Service launches properly, I can use http://127.0.0.1:8080/service?VERSION=1.3.0 to create a new WMS connection in QGIS.
However, the maximum resolution of this WMS layer is lower than that of the tiled layer. I check the (network) logs, and the deepest zoom level tiles mapproxy is requesting from the original tile source is 19. I confirm this by checking the directory cache_data/lorain_county_ohio_cache_EPSG3857: the deepest tiles there are zoom level 19 tiles.
What to write in mapproxy.yaml so that it is using all the zoom levels (in this case, down to 21) offered by the tilesource?

The number of zoom levels depends on the definition of the grid.
If you use a custom grid, you can set the zoom level as you wish, using num_levels (default: 20) or res (i.e. '[156543.033928, 78271.516964, 39135.758482, 19567.879241, 9783.9396205, 4891.96981025, 2445.98490513, 1222.99245256, 611.496226281, 305.748113141, 152.87405657, 76.4370282852, 38.2185141426, 19.1092570713, 9.55462853565, 4.77731426782, 2.38865713391, 1.19432856696, 0.597164283478, 0.298582141739]'). See https://mapproxy.github.io/mapproxy/latest/configuration.html.
services:
  wms:
    md:
      title: "Lorain County, Ohio WMS"
      abstract: "WMS service for Lorain County, Ohio orthophoto tiles"
    srs: ["EPSG:3857"]
    image_formats: ["image/jpeg"]
  demo:

layers:
  - name: lorain_county_ohio
    title: Lorain County, Ohio Orthophoto Tiles
    sources: [lorain_county_ohio_cache]

caches:
  lorain_county_ohio_cache:
    grids: [Spherical_Mercator]
    sources: [lorain_county_ohio_source]

sources:
  lorain_county_ohio_source:
    type: tile
    url: https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/vGBb7WYV10mOJRNM/arcgis/rest/services/2024_Spring_Aerials/MapServer/tile/%(z)d/%(y)d/%(x)d
    grid: Spherical_Mercator

grids:
  Spherical_Mercator:
     base: 'GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR'
     srs: 'EPSG:3857'
     num_levels: 22
     tile_size: [256,256]
     origin: nw

globals:
  cache:
    base_dir: "./cache_data"
    lock_dir: "./cache_data/locks"


